# Evento 'rowunselect' no funciona para CheckAll - jqxGrid

Tags: javascript, java

Estoy implementando 'checkbox mode' en mi jqxGrid y para seleccionar en forma masiva si funciona y ejecuta el código interior pero al quitar seleccionar masivo este no ejecuta el evento rowunselect (evento contrario al seleccionar que si funciona).

Mi consulta es estoy utilizando la sintaxis correcta para retirar los check's masivos? . Adjunto código;

1. Código JS que contruye grid:

   ```
       $(document).ready(function () 
   { var data = 
   [   
   {"CO_EMPR":"18","TI_REQI":"RAL","NU_REQI":"0001-0000000169","SECUENCIA":1,"CODIGO_ITEM":"330201064"},
   {"CO_EMPR":"18","TI_REQI":"RAL","NU_REQI":"0001-0000000169","SECUENCIA":2,"CODIGO_ITEM":"810101002"},
   {"CO_EMPR":"18","TI_REQI":"RAL","NU_REQI":"0001-0000000169","SECUENCIA":3,"CODIGO_ITEM":"500111003"}    ]; 
   var source = {localdata: data,  datatype: "array",datafields:
   [   {name:'CO_EMPR',type:'string'},
       {name:'TI_REQI',type:'string'},
       {name:'NU_REQI',type:'string'},
       {name:'SECUENCIA',type:'string'},
       {name:'CODIGO_ITEM',type:'string'} ],
   updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata, commit) {commit(true);}}; 
   var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
   $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid({
   width: '100%',
   height:'300',
   theme: 'theme',
   groupable: true,
   source: dataAdapter,
   selectionmode:  'none',
   editable:true,
   columnsautoresize: true,
   columnsresize:true,
   pageable:false,
   filterable: true,
   sortable: true,
   altrows: true, selectionmode: 'checkbox',
   ready: function () { 
   },
   columns: 
   [ 
   //{text: 'Seleccionar', datafield: 'available', columntype: 'checkbox', width: 40 }, 
   { text: 'CO_EMPR', datafield: 'CO_EMPR', width: 100 } , 
   { text: 'TI_REQI', datafield: 'TI_REQI', width: 100 }, 
   { text: 'NU_REQI', datafield: 'NU_REQI', width: 100 }, 
   { text: 'SECUENCIA', datafield: 'SECUENCIA', width: 100}  
   ]});
   });
   ```
2. Eventos 'rowselect' & 'rowunselect': Para seleccionar SI FUNCIONA 'rowselect' y para hacer lo contrario no ejecuta el evento.

   ```
           $('#GrillaJavaScript3').on('rowselect', function(event) {
           var args = event.args;
           var row = args.rowindex;
           if (Array.isArray(row)){
           $.each(row, function(index, value) {
           var datarow = $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid('getrowdata', value);
           //alert('If rowselect');
           Items_Migrar_OC_bkp(datarow.CO_EMPR,datarow.TI_REQI,datarow.NU_REQI,datarow.SECUENCIA ,1);
           });
           }else{
           var datarow = $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
           //alert('Else rowselect');
           Items_Migrar_OC_bkp(datarow.CO_EMPR,datarow.TI_REQI,datarow.NU_REQI,datarow.SECUENCIA ,1);
           }});

           $('#GrillaJavaScript3').on('rowunselect', function(event) {
           var args = event.args;
           var row = args.rowindex;
           if (Array.isArray(row)){
           $.each(row, function(index, value) {
           var datarow = $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid('getrowdata', value);
           alert('If rowselect');
           Items_Migrar_OC_bkp(datarow.CO_EMPR,datarow.TI_REQI,datarow.NU_REQI,datarow.SECUENCIA ,0);
           });
           }else{
           var datarow = $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
           alert('Else rowselect');
           Items_Migrar_OC_bkp(datarow.CO_EMPR,datarow.TI_REQI,datarow.NU_REQI,datarow.SECUENCIA ,0);
           }});
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto respuesta para activar y desactivar:

```
 $("#GrillaJavaScript3").bind('rowselect', function (event) {
        if (Array.isArray(event.args.rowindex)) {
            if (event.args.rowindex.length > 0) {
                //alert("All rows selected");
                // Si todo es seleccionado ingresa datos al array con valor: 1
                var args = event.args;
                var row = args.rowindex;
                if (Array.isArray(row)){
                $.each(row, function(index, value) {
                var datarow = $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid('getrowdata', value);
                //alert('If rowselect');
                Items_Migrar_OC(datarow.CO_EMPR,datarow.TI_REQI,datarow.NU_REQI,datarow.SECUENCIA, datarow.CODIGO_ITEM,
                datarow.CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA,datarow.CANTIDAD_ATENDIDA,datarow.CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE, 1);
                });
                }else{
                var datarow = $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
                //alert('Else rowselect');
                Items_Migrar_OC(datarow.CO_EMPR,datarow.TI_REQI,datarow.NU_REQI,datarow.SECUENCIA, datarow.CODIGO_ITEM,
                datarow.CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA,datarow.CANTIDAD_ATENDIDA,datarow.CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE, 1 );};
            } else {
                //alert("All rows unselected");
                Lista = [];
                console.log(Lista);
            }
        } else {
            //alert("Selected row has index = " + event.args.rowindex);
                var args = event.args;
                var row = args.rowindex;
                var datarow = $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
                Items_Migrar_OC(datarow.CO_EMPR,datarow.TI_REQI,datarow.NU_REQI,datarow.SECUENCIA, datarow.CODIGO_ITEM,
                datarow.CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA,datarow.CANTIDAD_ATENDIDA,datarow.CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE, 1 );
                //console.log(Lista_bkp); 
        }

         //Verificamos contenido del array
        //console.log(Lista_bkp);
    });

    $("#GrillaJavaScript3").bind('rowunselect', function (event) {
        //alert("Unselected row has index = " + event.args.rowindex);    
                var args = event.args;
                var row = args.rowindex;          
                var datarow = $('#GrillaJavaScript3').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
                Items_Migrar_OC(datarow.CO_EMPR,datarow.TI_REQI,datarow.NU_REQI,datarow.SECUENCIA, datarow.CODIGO_ITEM,
                datarow.CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA,datarow.CANTIDAD_ATENDIDA,datarow.CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE, 0 );

         //Verificamos contenido del array
        //console.log(Lista_bkp);
    });
```